# How do I open a GAE account on behalf of my company?

Tags: google-app-engine

We are planning to build an app on GAE that is going to be public-
facing.  Initially I thought of creating a special email ID like "gae-
dev@mycompany.com", sign up for GAE using that and develop/deploy apps on that account.

However, when I was trying to sign up for an account using this
special company email ID, I realized that I won't be able to provide
certain info such as date of birth.  I could have provided a bogus DOB
etc, however, the whole approach sounded hacky.

So, what is the official way for my company to get a GAE account?

I looked at GAE for small business.  This option seems suitable only for internal apps.

(note that the new apps is an external facing web site...  NOT an internal app
that only people with the company email ID can access)

Thanks in adv!

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/appengine/business/

Comment: GAE for small business is useful only for developing internal apps, as I understand.

Answer (score 1):

Sign up for App Engine with your work email, and have anyone else at the company that needs to do App Engine development do likewise. Then, add anyone who needs to be a developer as an administrator to each app they need it on. There's really no need to have a 'role account'.

Answer (score 0):

Does your company use Google Apps to handle email?

If so, you'd want to use this link to sign up for App Engine:
http://www.appspot.com/a/